# TAG! What am I?

Tags: riddle

Here's a nice easy one:

> To some I can be a real pain,
>   They figure me or go insane,
>   The best of me will always rhyme,
>   Though there are exceptions from time to carrot.

What am I?

Comment: I'm debating whether or not to add the [tag:rhyme] tag to this one ... ;-)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be "Brent Hackers"?

Comment: ...Et tu, @Sid?

Comment: How is this an actual *riddle*? I mean, there's meant to be some actual tricksiness about a riddle, no?

Comment: Sorry @GarethMcCaughan but I tested this on a friend of sub-normal intellect who took over an hour to figure it out.  ...and then kicked himself.  Hard.  So I'd say it's at least a low-entry-level difficulty.  Gotta have those too!

Comment: Hm. Not many people of sub-normal intellect active on PSE, and any puzzle designed for them is going to get solved by the people of super-normal intellect before they get a chance...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Fair enough, but I frequently look at solved puzzles to stretch my brain, and I feel big and smart when I can figure one out without looking at the other answers. ...even when it's an easy win.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps it's

> a riddle?

Title: "TAG! What am I?"

> The answer is in the tag on the question.

*To some I can be a real pain,*

> Sometimes a pain to solve.

*They figure me or go insane,*

> Argh! What is the solution?!

*The best of me will always rhyme,*

> Rhyming riddles are often the best.

*Though there are exceptions from time to carrot.*

> But some riddles don't rhyme - like this one, but only because the last word was changed from "time" to "carrot".

Comment: Figured it would be a quick one.  Well done. +1

Answer (score 0):

I quickly scrolled down to post my answer.

Not to look at others.

> The tittle gave it away for me : TAG :)

it's a :

> riddle
>  also, a riddle fits with all the verse .

To some I can be a real pain

> its true riddle can be painfull when you don't find the solution...

They figure me or go insane,

> sometimes they could make people insane ^^

The best of me will always rhyme,

> the best riddle often rhyme :)

Though there are exceptions from time to carrot.

> except this one  :D

Thought it was a great one thx !

Answer (score -2):

You could be a cipher (instead of a riddle) ie difficult to "figure out". Unless, of course, the encryption key used has LOW entropy. I initially thought the entropy connection was to do with figuring out where carrots would grow on a large, albeit, finite patch of land, the low entropy being where one would most likely guess they're growing (near a well or riverbank). However carrot (not right ie an exception to being decrypted correctly) is CLOSE to the word carnot as in the "carnot cycle" which relates to the subject of entropy in thermodynamics.

Do I get a carrot for this answer? :)

PS- It took me 5 minutes to get this.

Comment: So the word carrot was just an arbitrary choice to end the line without rhyming? Surely "red herring" would have been a better choice that carrot. If this is the case I think the "riddle" is a little too simplistic that it would send many people off thinking about it too much!